# Error: “Unresolved function or method present()” when using LoadingController

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

**ISSUE:**

When I use the LoadingController in my project, I see the following error: `"Unresolved function or method present()"`

Here is the screenshot code that I have in my file:

[image: Unresolved function or method present()”]

As we can see from the screenshot, there are 2 pieces of code that show the same error. The code from lines: 51-61 are a direct copy of the code from the ionic documentation that can be seen under [Usage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading#usage)

The code from lines: 63-69 are the trimmed down and basic version of the code and for testing purposes `await` is removed in front of the `loading.present();`. Yet it throws the same error as the original code above.

**GOAL:**

What can we do to fix the issue so that Intellij Idea (IDE) stops complaining about the same?

Following is the info from my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "gf",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure it is the right way to do it but i managed to Intellij to stop whining

```
return (<any>loading).present();
```